# MYSQL Query - Get and check data from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Table name USERS where I store all my users. I get the user I want by using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = 'Jack'
```

That's working nicely.

I also have another table called "Activity" when I store users following's.

I now would like to be do a query where I select the user's using the first query and then check if I am already following this user from the "Activity" table.

My "Activity" table is setup like this:

id (for the current user / me)

IdOtherUser (the id of the user that I am following)

type (type which is 'follow')

I know this is possible but as I am quite new to MYSQL I haven't seemed to figure it out yet, I have also checked for other similar question but have not found any helpfull!

If you know any good answers already please let me know!

Any help is much appreciated, and thanks in advance to anyone that can help!!

**Possible solution?**

```
SELECT
  *,
  a.type
FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN Activity a
   ON a.idOtherUser = u.id AND a.id = 145
WHERE u.id = 86
```

Comment: u need to `join` them so any common columns between them??

Comment: Can you please show us your tables? Using a better method than telling us verbally, + we don't know what your Users table looks like, thanks. :-)

Comment: Your solution needs to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN rather than an INNER JOIN, and you need to move the check for activity.type from the WHERE clause into the ON clause. The check for Activity.IdOtherUser in the WHERE clause can just be removed. This will return one row for each matching activity for that user.

Comment: @Kickstart What about the other stuff in the ON Clause do I leave that and just add the Activity.type = 'follow'?

Comment: Leave the other bits on the ON clause. Your query as you currently have it will only return a user if they have an activity - no activity for that user = user not returned. With a LEFT OUTER JOIN you can return them whether they have an activity or not, then put out a flag to say if they have an activity. But if you put the check in the WHERE clause then it must check that value in the WHERE clause; as you are checking for a value on the activity table then it must have had a match, so it would turn it effectively into an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Kickstart Ok got it now, just 1 last thing how do i put out a flag to check if they have an actvity

Comment: You could use an aggregate function (to make sure you only have 1 row for each user), and wrap that with an IF statement, as I did in my answer.

Comment: @Kickstart Can't get it right, driving me mad....Soon as I manage I'll let you know.

Comment: @Kickstart I'm probably asking for too much, but could you create a qucik working example for me?

Comment: Could you paste up the table declares and a couple of lines of sample data, along with what you expect to be output for those sample lines please? (although about to go out for the evening so maybe tomorrow).

Comment: Ok I will, If I cant figure it out by tonight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `join`:
[SQL - Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.username,
  a.type
FROM USERS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Activity a
   ON u.id = a.id
WHERE a.IdOtherUser = 139
```

Check this one, it should work fine :) If you wonder what are these a, u, they are just aliases defined near column name.

**IF Syntax:**

> IF(expression ,expr_true, expr_false);

Comment: Hi, thanks what would you need to improve this..? tried it but nreturns nil, I guess because there's no user in the query

Comment: You need to have in those 2 tables common columns (such as ID), and then you just `join` on your table another table. I will combine them. In my exaple above it will combine those tables by `id` in `USER` table and `IdOtherUser` in `Activity` table, and if there will be same values, you will receive some rows.

Comment: I have created my own solution which seems to be working, check it out see if it's alright or needs fixing....? if so you can update your answer with it

Comment: Check this one I have posted :)

Comment: It's sort of working, but if there is no activity/ I am not following it returns null. I need it to return anything anyway.. As I need the user details

Comment: Nope, I think it has to do with the Where type = 'follow'. Because if there isn't a follow that row wont exsist, So I need to make that optional?

Comment: Yes, if `a.type` will be different than `'follow'` it will return 0 rows. You can get rows with just `WHERE a.IdOtherUser = 139`, and then in your PHP code (f.ex. `if ($row['type'] == 'follow') { echo "Okay!"};`

Comment: Well how do I avoid that? What I am trying to achieve is: Get the user's details from the USERS table and then check if the current user(another person) is already following the person clicked(the person I am getting th user details for)... But If I am not following there will be no rows in the Activity Table, but I still need it to return the User details regardless

Comment: I removed the Where type but no difference if there is no following no results get returned

Comment: only returns results if I am following

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN`. Im just wondering why it returns null if there is no `a.type = 'follow'`, what if u delete whole `WHERE` ?

Comment: It returns all the follows, from other users and other stuff

Comment: Check again that i posted :)

Comment: Definitely better!! I added above in my question what seems to be working, used your new query to get it..! could you tell me if it looks alright? +1 anyway, I'll try a few more times and if it still works I will accept

Comment: I think it is okay :) Most important is if it works for you :) If I helped I will be thankful for accept my answer :)

Comment: Let's hope it is okay, I will accept your answer. Come in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126754/discussion-between-jack-and-karol-gasienica).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and GROUP BY to count the number of matches (which might be 0), and us IF to check if there are activities or not:-

```
SELECT u.id, 
    u.name,
    IF(COUNT(a.user_id) > 0, 'Activities', 'No Activities')
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN activity a
ON u.id = a.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Comment: Hi , I have actually come up with a solution my self...It's seeming to work If I post it above could you check it for me? or make any fixes in it and change your answer to it so I can accept it?

Comment: But if you solution is better let me know